# Getting different behavior between iOS simulator and iPhone deploy

Tags: swift, xcode7-beta2

After updating from Xcode 7 beta to Xcode 7 beta 2 I've started getting odd behavior in my tableView rows.

**A few points to mention:**

- I am not to the stage where I am editing my user interface, everything is set to its initial defaults.
- I have not changed any of my prototype cell defaults in IB
- Nor have I changed any table attributes programmatically.
- My code base has not changed since I upgraded.
- This is new behavior since the update.

**This is from my simulator (everything is fine):**

[image]

**This is from my iPhone (some cells are black):**
[image]

### My question is:

Is anyone familiar with this behavior? If so, what can I do to fix this?

---

*note: extra content deleted for clarity; see answer.*

Comment: Are you sure the background for your cells and tableviews are all set to white?

Comment: It appears to me that all that's changed is the default background colors of tableview and/or tableviewcell, keep in mind that tableviewcell's contentView has at least one superview that used to be the tableviewcell itself, check all the views and go from there. Not saying that the issue is going to remain, this is a beta preview after all, but that should help for now.

Comment: @matt it turned out that it was because I was running iOS 8 on my iPhone, I updated to iOS 9 beta and now my table's are white again.

Comment: @matt it told me it was ineligible, I unplugged it, plugged it in and it worked. Strange, I'll mention that in my answer.

Comment: "it told me it was ineligible, I unplugged it, plugged it in and it worked." You should mention _that_ in your answer too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Xcode 7 beta 2 was allowing me to deploy to my iPhone with iOS 8 installed on it. Which I've been told by someone in the know, should probably not be possible.

**Steps I used to reproduce:**

- Using Xcode 7 beta 2 create a simple project with a tableViewController.
- deploy the project to iphone 6 simulator (see white background)
- deploy the project to iphone 6 with iOS 8 (see black background)

My first attempt to deploy to iOS 8, my device was marked as ineligible. I uplugged the device and plugged it back in. It took a bit longer to deploy than usual but when it did, it had a black background to all of my table views.

**Solution:**

I installed iOS 9 beta 2 on my iPhone 6 and everything works as expected.